# Get series of ranges from series of values

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I was wondering how to get a series of ranges from a series of values. What I mean by this is assume I have a list of numbers: `list_values = [4, 3, 4, 4]`,

and I want to convert this to a series of ranges like this (ignoring the structure of the data for now):

```
0: 0 - 4
1: 4 - 8
2: 8 - 13
3: 13 - 18
```

Where the size of the ith range corresponds to the ith index from the list of numbers.

Here's what I've tried so far (and other variations of the same basic logic). For simplicity, and because I'm stuck on this, I only calculated the 'start' value for now, the beginning value of the range (0, 4, 8, 13 ...):

```
range_start = [0] 
for i, list_values in enumerate(list):
    range_start[i+1] = range_start[i] + list_values[i] + 1
```

The logic here is recursive in nature, that the next value of the start range is equal to the previous value, plus the (i-1)th list_value, plus 1. Notice the first iteration of the loop, `range_start[1] = range_start[0] + list_value[0] + 1 = 4`

However, I keep getting an error saying `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. I'm confused since I'm only doing integer math, and not subsetting anything.

I'd like the output to be some form of the ranges as a list or tuple similar to this:

```
[[0, 4], [4, 8], [8, 13], [13, 18]]
```

Any help is great, thanks!

Comment: `list` is a reserved keyword in python, please avoid using it.

Comment: Yes, true. I've changed the variable names from my code for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want an answer without importing anything.

```
list_values = [4, 3, 4, 4]
range_start = []
start = 0
for i, k in enumerate(list_values):
    if start == 0:
        new_range = [start, start + k]
    else:
        new_range = [range_start[i-1][1], start + k]
    range_start.append(new_range)
    start += k + 1
```

Gives you a `range_start` output of: `[[0, 4], [4, 8], [8, 13], [13, 18]]`

Comment: Thanks, that's an elegant solution. Appreciate it.

Comment: I realized I made a mistake in my question! I've edited my question to reflect that. The ranges should be [[0, 4], [4, 8], [8, 13], [13, 18]]. I could edit the sublists, but I really liked this solution, any idea the logic to fix it?

Comment: That produces a list: [[0, 4], [4, 7], [7, 11], [11, 15]]. Still just a little off! I've tried many variations, but none seem to work.

Comment: I misread your change, edited the code to do what you were looking for. You should update your pattern description though if you need code that is usable with different range starts.

Comment: Edited the code again to what I think would be more consistent logically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to generate the list of right endpoints, and then use a second iteration to generate the left endpoints. The right endpoint grows as you add the bucket widths, and the left endpoint at any given point is the last right endpoint plus one.

```
from itertools import accumulate

list_values = [4, 3, 4, 4]

ranges = []

endpoints = list(accumulate(list_values))

for idx, value in enumerate(endpoints):
    # These ranges are closed on the left and 
    # the right.
    if idx == 0:
        ranges.append((1, value))
    else:
        ranges.append((endpoints[idx-1] + 1, value))
```

```
print(ranges)
[(1, 4), (5, 7), (8, 11), (12, 15)]
```

The reason for your `IndexError` is that `list_values` is an element of your list (an integer; you're shadowing your outer list in this name) and `list_values[i]` attempts to access it as if it were a list.

Comment: Great! I think it's just a little bit off, but I can't find out how to fix it (first time with itertools). The right endpoints after the first, seem to be 1 off. I'm using these values in a for loop range. So range(5, 7) would only run 2 times, when it should run 3.

Comment: These are ranges closed on the right and the left, so you should be able to write `for rng in ranges: left, right = rng; for i in range(left, right + 1): ...`

Comment: I had never used accumulate, nice one!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

prev = 0
for idx, n in enumerate(l):
  for i in range(prev, prev + n + 1):
    result[idx].append(i)
  prev = i + 1

print(result)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 1: [5, 6, 7, 8], 2: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 3: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]})
```

EDIT inspired by @crcvd's answer:

```
from itertools import accumulate

l= [4, 3, 4, 4]

result = {}
prev = 0
for idx, last in enumerate(accumulate(l)):
  result[idx] = list(range(idx + prev, last + idx + 1))
  prev = last
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
l = [4, 3, 4, 4] 
k = [sum(l[:i])+a+i for i, a in enumerate(l)]
#as full ranges
result = [list(range(a, b+1)) for a, b in zip([0]+k[:-1], k)]
#start and end indices:
result = list(zip([0]+k[:-1], k))
```

Output

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
[(0, 4), (4, 8), (8, 13), (13, 18)]
```